# How to do imports between files in a python module using __init__.py file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module, python-packaging

This is what my directory looks like:

```
my_library
├── my_module
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── core.py
│   ├── helpers.py
│   └── interface.py
├── __init__.py
├── setup.py
└── README.md
```

`core.py` contains the main class `Generator`, `interface.py` contains a bunch of variables and functions that the user would want to use alongside the class (to set parameters etc.) and finally `helpers.py` contains a bunch of functions used by `core.py` that the user has no interest in.
I'm trying to use the helper functions defined within `helper.py` (which in turn use parameters from `interface.py`) in `core.py`. My question is what is an optimal way to do the imports within the three module files and in `__init__.py`? My goal is that when the user does `my_module.` they will be able to access the `Generator` class and everything in the `interface.py` file but not what's in `helpers.py` (at least not directly, they would have to go one more level down).

My `my_module`'s `__init__.py` currently looks like this:

```
from .core import Generator
from .interface import *
from .base_functions import *
```

`core.py` and `helper.py` both have a `import my_module` for `helper.py` to  use what's defined in `interface.py` and `core.py` to use what's defined in both the others.

What I have currently does the job to a certain extent, but I'm not sure it's optimal, especially I read that using asterisk (`*`) imports isn't a good idea.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I found that read that might be helpful: https://towardsdatascience.com/whats-init-for-me-d70a312da583

Comment: IMO using asterisk imports in an `__init__.py` file is fine.